# Unable to lock screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, lock-screen, external-monitor, xdg

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with default DE on my laptop.
I have an external monitor that I used for weeks without problem.

(maybe during an update) I closed the lid and then the desktop appeared on the second screen and it didn't lock the session as expected.

From that day when I try to lock the screen (via shortcut, menu or `xdg-screensaver lock`), gnome freezes and restart itself after 1 minute.

Gnome extensions:

- system-monitor
- sound input & output device chooser; openweather

~~Disabling extensions doesn't help.~~ (Actually yes it does, see edit 2)

I don't know how to solve this problem but I can provide logs and other info if needed.

Thank you :)

EDIT 1: 
Found information on `syslog`:
 https://pastebin.com/SXHjzdMh

It seems a crash due to a failed assertion,

`May  5 19:03:57 enrico-ultrabook org.gnome.Shell.desktop[31212]: St:ERROR:../src/st/st-bin.c:186:st_bin_destroy: assertion failed: (priv->child == NULL)`

EDIT 2:
Actually disabling the top switch in the extensions window in gnome-tweaks gnome freezes and restarts. So I think it's a problem related to extensions. See log https://pastebin.com/g4iWFD5Q

It seems a problem related to system-monitor `May 13 16:18:25 enrico-ultrabook gnome-shell[6617]: error reading: /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/fan1_input`

It seems a bug reported [here](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet/issues/601)

Comment: Looks like a reported bug, does this help?  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1867763

Comment: @dlin thank you, but no it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Since I restarted my system without the above extension `system-monitor` I dont experience the issue anymore for a week. This morning I reenabled it and the problem came back...